Options Setting Pre-Hung Door on Foundation Top
I removed my old door and installed a pre-hung door. The former door was lying on top of the foundation. This base was highly irregular so I struggled to use a level and doubted I could just lay the pre-hung door directly on top.
I ended up putting this left-over roof underlayment membrane (just sliced a rectangle to length) then placing a piece of shimmed OSB on top, then the door. The installation was fine, but lacking professional feedback I'm wondering if the following options would have been better:

Could I have used a grinder/hammer drill with a point to rectify the top of the foundation, getting rid of any irregularities then checking for level, then put the membrane and then the prehung door instead?
Could I have cleaned up, brushed some of that liquid concrete adhesive then apply some fast-bonding cement to get a nice clean, level surface then installed the frame on top?

I feel that no one would do the second option because you would have a rough opening and need to wait for the cement to cure a bit before resuming installation, just have a hard time believing anyone doing installations would bother with that, still open to feedback.
Reason being that I find the new door is 5/8" higher than my front door (the OSB + the shims raised the whole thing a tiny bit, which is really no big deal, but I have more doors to install and I want to make sure future installs are done according to best practices.
I have a low-res picture of what the exposed foundation top looked like after I removed the old door:

